# how do the SAP people look at PowerBuilder

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I am a Java/C# programmer, now I join a company which has some projects developed by PowerBuilder. I just wonder how does the SAP people (the people work for SAP but not from Sybase) look at PowerBuilder? Will SAP give up PowerBuilder? Many thanks.

Comment: Try this type of questions at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

PowerBuilder makes money. SAP likes money.

'nuf said.

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with SAP for more than 4 years and I do not even know what Powerbuilder is.

Comment: "Working *with* SAP" (the product) or "working *for* SAP" (the company)? I think YJ is asking about the latter. It's not unusual for the user of a product to be unaware of other products produced by the same manufacturer. I bet most PowerBuilder users have no idea what Advantage Database is, and that fact has no relevance at all to the lives of Advantage Database users. (I know. I've met some. Had to ask. They didn't care. <g>)

Answer (score 0):

I've been working *with* SAP for 5 years or so, and *for* SAP for almost 1 year now.

The only Sybase product I've ever heard of (and actually used) is Sybase Unwired Platform, but I guess that is because the current team I'm part of is pretty much focused on mobile and ERP solutions.

Answering your question: I don't believe SAP will give up PowerBuilder, but that's just my opinion.